# difference between pipe and pipe- while writing to a program

Tags: perl

Different ways to write data to a program

**Way1:**

```
open(WRITEME, "| program arguments");
print WRITEME "data\n";
close(WRITEME);
```

**Way2:**

```
open(WRITEME, "|-", "program arguments");
print WRITEME "data\n";
close(WRITEME);
```

Please explain, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

There are differences between the two forms in other cases<sup>[1]</sup>, but there are no differences for the example given.

However, there is one benefit of using the three-argument form of which one can take advantage when using this function of `open`. `open`, like `system`, will run the program directly (rather than invoking a shell to execute it) when the command is passed as a list of multiple values. This means that the following avoids invoking a shell:

```
open(WRITEME, "|-", "program", "arguments");
```

There are many benefits to avoiding the shell middle-man. The primary benefit is the lack of need to convert variables into shell literals. In other words,

```
open(WRITEME, "|-", "program", "--", $file);
```

is a simple way of doing

```
use Shell::StringQuote qw( shell_quote );
open(WRITEME, "| ".shell_quote("program", "--", $file));
```

---

1. For example, there are differences between `open(my $fh, $x)` and `open(my $fh, '<', $x)`. There are even differences between `open(my $fh, "< $x")` and `open(my $fh, '<', $x)`.

Comment: can you please explain the D/B `open(my $fh, "< $x") ` and `open(my $fh, '<', $x) `

Answer (score 0):

**Way1** uses two-argument `open`.

This will open a pipe to *program arguments* and write to it. The alternative is `"program arguments |"` with the `|` at the end, which will make the program read instead.<sup>1</sup>

**Way2** uses three-argument `open`, (which is preferred for files). The `|-` says that the *programm arguments* should be run as a command, and we pipe output into that command. The alternative is `-|`, which means we read from that command.

This is documented in [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

> For three or more arguments if MODE is |- , the filename is interpreted as a command to which output is to be piped, and if MODE is -| , the filename is interpreted as a command that pipes output to us. In the two-argument (and one-argument) form, one should replace dash (- ) with the command. See Using open() for IPC in perlipc for more examples of this. (You are not allowed to open to a command that pipes both in and out, but see IPC::Open2, IPC::Open3, and Bidirectional Communication with Another Process in perlipc for alternatives.)

---

For both of them, you should use a lexical filehandle instead of the GLOB one, and catch errors.

```
open my $fh, '|-', 'ls' or die $!;
```

You should also read [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).

<sup>1) I cannot find this in the docs right now.</sup>